# Android: text color holo light

Tags: android, listview, themes

I just have a stupid question...
I am using (or better, I suppose to use) the theme holo light in my application: I have set it in the manifest file.
Look at the screenshot below: the text is too light, isn't it? Ok, I know that I can set it but my question is: is it the real text color in holo theme or there is an error in my application? I suppose it because it's strange that in google an illegibile color like this was chosen.

[image]

EDIT:

I set the theme with the attribute

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

of the application element.
Here is the listview code whick I populated with a listfragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/songsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:textFilterEnabled="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songsFragment_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:lines="1">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songsFragment_artistTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:lines="1" 
        android:textSize="14sp">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Which layout do you inflate in your ListView Adapter?

Comment: The layout you find above... Isn't it? Sorry I think I don't understand what you mean :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you create your Adapter, are you using the application context or the activity? I just ran into the exact same problem but noticed if I generated my Array Adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables);
            setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Then the text was appearing white.  If, however, I used the activity context (so if I was doing the above in the onCreate method, I could just use "this") the text was black.  I think somehow my app was overriding the theme.  Perhaps that is / was your issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are picking up the default theme, which has a default text colour of #bfbfbf. My guess would be that you are running the app on a 2.x version of Android, which does not have the Holo light theme installed.

Comment: Well.. Not I am running the app on android jelly bean 4.1