# How to apply default holo light theme to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, android-theme, android-styles

Please refer to the linked image.

[image]

I applied the light theme by using appTheme for my application with

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
</resources>
```

in `styles.xml`

I try to conform to standards so I did minimal styling. The result however, looks faded, it gives an inactive feel. Concerns:

- Somehow the groups and childs get styled because they look different than the edittext added for reference - especially the checkboxes to the right are almost invisible.

How to fix? I know I can just set text color, but I try to inherit from standard styles here.
Note: I added style `holo.light.expandablelistview` randomly, no effect

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- style="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView.White" -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/targetsList"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummyText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Group

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="fill" 
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ExpandableListView">

    <!-- PARENT -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/parentname"
              android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox" 
              android:focusable="false"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
              android:freezesText="false"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:padding="0px" 
                android:minHeight="35dp">

    <!-- CHILD -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox" 
              android:focusable="false"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
              android:freezesText="false"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="5px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, have a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074401/android-text-color-holo-light. It might help you.